# Access Thymeleaf validation errors using a new instance of BindingResult interface

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to validate a form with the `Spring Framework` using a `BindingResult` interface, but without put to a model object (as usual).

So, I create a new instance of the [BeanPropertyBindingResult](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BeanPropertyBindingResult.html) class, perform validation, but when return to the view (Thymeleaf template engine) I can't access the **error object**.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/contracheque/salario", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String contrachequeSalario(@RequestParam Calendar dataComissao, @RequestParam BigDecimal salarioComissao, Model model) {
    Profissional profissional = profissionalService.getProfissional(1);

    // Create a BindingResult without a ModelAttribute
    BindingResult result = new BeanPropertyBindingResult("result", "formSalarioComissao");

    // --> Make a simple validation...
    if (dataComissao == null) {
        result.reject("dataComissao", Constantes.VALIDATE_MSG_OBRIGATORIO);
    }
    if (salarioComissao == null) {
        result.reject("salarioComissao", Constantes.VALIDATE_MSG_OBRIGATORIO);
    }

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("result", result);

        return "financeiro/comissao/contrachequeSalario";
    }

    return "redirect:/...";
}
```

This is the output of the `result` object

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Error in object 'formSalarioComissao': codes [dataComissao.formSalarioComissao,dataComissao]; arguments []; default message [val.obrigatorio]
Error in object 'formSalarioComissao': codes [salarioComissao.formSalarioComissao,salarioComissao]; arguments []; default message [val.obrigatorio]
```

I can't use the Thymeleaf tag `th:error=""` because I am outside scope of `th:object=""` (or better informed, I don't have this object in the form).

This is the output when using call the method `getAllErrors()` of class `org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult`.

```
[
    Error in object 'formSalarioComissao': codes [dataComissao.formSalarioComissao,dataComissao]; arguments []; default message [val.obrigatorio],
    Error in object 'formSalarioComissao': codes [salarioComissao.formSalarioComissao,salarioComissao]; arguments []; default message [val.obrigatorio]
]
```

An interesting detail, when I call the methods `getFieldError(String field)` or `getFieldErrors()` there are `null`.

Is there a correct way to access the `error object` to display the validation message?
Such that, it must be informed that the message code to the  `messages.properties` file?